# ESTBeaconConnection makes Estimote beacon undiscoverable

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ibeacon, estimote

My question is about the Estimote SDK for iOS.
I’m having a problem when pairing a beacon. When the beacon is connected to the device using `ESTBeaconConnection`, for temperature reading, it turns not discoverable for other devices until I disconnect (`.disconnect()`) from this beacon.
How can I keep all beacons always discoverable?

Comment: Do you mean discoverable as a BLE core Bluetooth device or as a beacon from core location?

Comment: Discoverable in some way I could read rssi and proximity. So, I would say as a beacon from CoreLocation.

Comment: do not pair them anytime... just connect

Comment: @Materazzi06, pair means connect using Estimote SDK (I guess). The class `ESTBeaconConnection` pairs the beacon with the device. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth LE devices generally stop advertising when a connection is established.  This is a limitation of the way they are designed.  Unfortunately, if you need to make a connection to read the temperature, the device will not be advertising itself while the connection is active.

Answer (score 0):

I just received an e-mail from the Estimote team saying:

> While paired, beacons can't be seen by other devices, because they
>   stop broadcasting. That's one of Bluetooth 4.0 limitations.

Bad luck.
Thanks everyone!

Comment: If I don't pair, I don't get the temperature + battery information. I have to pair. The question was: when paired, how to keep the beacons advertising while paired. The answer is, as I understood: not possible. But I do have to pair.

Comment: If you need to access temperature and battery voltage info, you can switch the beacons to broadcast Eddystone instead of iBeacon. Eddystone frames in Estimote Beacons come with the Eddystone TLM (telemetry) frame broadcast once every 12 seconds that contains temperature and battery voltage.